# Flutter: Too many positional arguments in the getPermission function using geolocation package

Tags: flutter, geolocation, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter geolocation package to get the current location of the user. But while asking for permission from the user, I am getting the error: Too many positional arguments in the LocationPermission(). Can anyone please help me?

```
getPermission() async {
        final GeolocationResult result =
            await Geolocation.requestLocationPermission(const LocationPermission(
                android: LocationPermissionAndroid.fine,
                ios: LocationPermissionIOS.always));
        return result;
      }
```

[Screenshot of the problem is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvRu4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/geolocation/latest/geolocation/Geolocation/requestLocationPermission.html) and the error, `requestLocationPermission` has no positional arguments, so the usage would be:

```
getPermission() async {
    final GeolocationResult result =
        await Geolocation.requestLocationPermission(permission: const LocationPermission(
            android: LocationPermissionAndroid.fine,
            ios: LocationPermissionIOS.always));
    return result;
  }
```